# Chrome Extension get callback from Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

Is there anyway to get an alert when chrome activate CSP screen like:

The site ahead contains malware

Attackers currently on XXXXX might attempt to install dangerous programs on your Mac that steal or delete your information (for example, photos, passwords, messages, and credit cards).

```
var preXhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
preXhr.open("GET", url, true);
preXhr.send();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, if Chrome activates CSP during execution and the error is not caught, it is logged to console. If you want to display your own message somewhere, you could put a `try/catch` block around the code that is getting executed. In the `catch` block, call a function that will check for the different CSP errors and write your own custom logic.